# Eclipse photon unable to read repository

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling

I would like to update Eclipse version.
System reported pop-up window:

Unable to read repository at http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/photon/r/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers.
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/photon/r/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers is not a valid repository location.

And Problem occurred says:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=C__Users_Lukas_eclipse_committers-photon_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit,5.2.0.201809290756
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.core,5.2.0.201809290756
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.doc,5.2.0.201809290756
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.gitflow,5.2.0.201809290756
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.gitflow.ui,5.2.0.201809290756
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.ui,5.2.0.201809290756
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.ui,5.2.0.201809290756
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.archive,5.2.0.201809280023
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit,5.2.0.201809290756
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit.gitflow.feature,5.2.0.201809290756
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit.mylyn,5.2.0.201809290756
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit,5.2.0.201809280023
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jgit,5.2.0.201809280042
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Do you already have a Photon version installed, or are you attempting to upgrade from an older release? (see the notes on http://download.eclipse.org/releases/photon/)

Comment: because that is not a valid update-site. What made you think you can simply use this in the "install software" dialog?

Comment: I have a Photon app, but I would attempt to upgrade new version of Photon

Comment: @LukasGužauskas the link in my comment should be the correct repository for photon. It is typically already contained in the pre-populated list of "Available Software Sites". Have you already tried to remove the package-download link and just try again?